# How can I add HTTP Request Header to Silverlight RIA Requests

Tags: silverlight, http-headers, ria

I have a need to pass an HTTP header for each an every RIA Service request being made from a Silverlight app. The value of the header needs to come from the app instance, and not from a cookie. I know this can be accomplished by putting it in the DTOs, but it's not an option because a lot of our service calls use Entities and change sets, so there's no base class to tie into for all requests. So I'm looking for a centralized and safe means to pass something back with each request so the developers do not have to worry with it. A custom HTTP header would work fine, but I don't know how to intercept the outbound request to set it.

Anyone have any ideas I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the lower level you can add HTTP headers with the help of an `IClientMessageInspector`. Try starting from [this post on SL forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/408990.aspx).

The next step depends on your use cases.

If the value of the header must be the same for any method called by the `DomainContext`, then you may just extend the context using partial class, add a property for the header value and use that property in the inspector.

If you need to pass a different value for each method call, you'd probably need to wrap your `DomainContext` into another class and add an argument to each method of the context that will accept the header value and pass it to the inspector somehow. Needless to say, without a code-generator this would be hard.

Here's an adapted sample from the SL forum for the first case:

```
public sealed partial class MyDomainContext
{
  public string HeaderValue { get; set; }

  partial void OnCreated()
  {
    WebDomainClient<IMyDomainServiceContract> webDomainClient = (WebDomainClient<IMyDomainServiceContract>)DomainClient;
    CustomHeaderEndpointBehavior customHeaderEndpointBehavior = new CustomHeaderEndpointBehavior(this);
    webDomainClient.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(customHeaderEndpointBehavior);
  }
}

public class CustomHeaderEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
  MyDomainContext _Ctx;

  public CustomHeaderEndpointBehavior(MyDomainContext ctx)
  {
    this._Ctx = ctx;
  }      

  public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }
  public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
  {
    clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomHeaderMessageInspector(this._Ctx));
  }
  public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }
  public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }
}

public class CustomHeaderMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
  MyDomainContext _Ctx;

  public CustomHeaderMessageInspector(MyDomainContext ctx)
  {
    this._Ctx = ctx;
  }

  public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState) {}
  public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel)
  {
    string myHeaderName = "X-Foo-Bar";
    string myheaderValue = this._Ctx.HeaderValue;

    HttpRequestMessageProperty property = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
    property.Headers[myHeaderName] = myheaderValue;
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. In fact, I should I've known since I used the WCF extension points to do something similar on the server. Thanks Pavel!.