# How to intercept any WCF/Ria Service call on client?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I want to intercept any calls to a Ria Service in Silverlight, so that I can then show a loader. Is it possible through some WCF Api or do I have to write my own solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a partial class of you context class and in the `OnCreated` partial method add some client side behavior like `IClientMessageInspector` which provides `BeforeSendRequest` and `AfterReceiveReply` methods.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434357/how-can-i-add-htt-request-header-to-silverlight-ria-requests) or this [blog post](http://www.lucbos.net/2011/02/normal-0-21-false-false-false-nl-be-x.html).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it sure is useful. However, my application has multiple domain contexts and I'd like to find a way to make it global for all WCF calls, so that I don't have to remember about creating a partial for each context. I see your answer as a way to achieve this by changing the way RIA generates classes, but I'd rather not mess with it if it can be omitted.

Comment: If you declare a 'behaviorExtensions' referencing a single DLL, then in your client 'endpoint' tag you reference that with 'behaviorConfiguration', all your client WCF calls will be captured without any code. The DLL I mention has a class implementing 'IClientMessageInspector'. This will work if your using a .config file for your client WCF connection properties. Let me know if you need more details.